# What is the gravitational force of a intangible sphere inside another sphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

This is similar to the problem of the gravitational force of a particle inside a sphere, but instead of a particle, I want to know how two objects of non-negligible size and mass would interact gravitationally when inside one another if they didn't collide with each other like this:

[image]

Edit: The bodies would be spheres with equally distributed matter in all of their points

Comment: I suggest a straightforward way to solve this problem is to treat one of the objects as cut into two parts (exactly at the intersection with the second object).

Comment: are these two spheres, or two disks?  What is the matter distribution of the objects?  Another suggestion for an approach for this would be to first compute $g$ everywhere, due to the first object, and then compute ${\vec F} = \int dm\, {\vec g}$ everywhere for the second object.

Comment: Doesn't the shell theorem and superposition apply?

Comment: Please, clarify the following points. 1) Does the drawing represent the situation you want to discuss, or it represents the situation that you want to exclude? It would be better to have a drawing representing what you want and another one representing what you exclude. 2) Are you considering solid spheres, or spherical surfaces? What does it mean that a solid sphere is inside another solid sphere, without colliding?

Comment: @garyp I think it does. Pick any point inside the object and you can technically cancel out everything which belongs to a larger radius on both spheres. So what remains is "what is below the feet". And I also think that one can just calculate the contributions of the two spheres (or subspheres) (technically balls i guess) separately and just add them together... Treat them as "point sources"